# Prism-Mvvm app deployment error on Mobile Emulator

Tags: mvvm, uwp, prism

I got a exception when deploying a simple Prism.Mvvm app on Mobile Emulator 10586,while it works on simulator as well as on my local machine.
I am referencing to Prism.storeapps package.Here is my code

App.xaml.cs

```
namespace MvvmSample
{
    sealed partial class App : MvvmAppBase
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public enum Expirences
        {
            Main
        }
        protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(Expirences.Main.ToString(), null);
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<controls:PageBase
    x:Class="MvvmSample.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns:controls="using:MvvmSample.Controls"
    xmlns:prism="using:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MvvmSample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <d:Page.DataContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel/>
    </d:Page.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="29.333" />
    </Grid>
</controls:PageBase>
```

View

```
namespace MvvmSample
{
    namespace Controls
    {
        public abstract partial class PageBase : Page, IView { }
    }
    namespace Views
    {
        public sealed partial class MainPage : Controls.PageBase
        {
            public MainPage()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
    }
    namespace ViewModels
    {
        public class MainPageViewModel : Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.ViewModel
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public MainPageViewModel()
            {
                this.Title = "Run Time";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the deployment error say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [Prism.StoreApps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.StoreApps/), which is a package for Windows 8.1. For UWP you should be using [Prism.Windows](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Windows/). The reason why it is working on your machine, is because Windows 10 can run Windows 8 apps. While the emulator is a specific SDK build.

For more info on the available NuGet packages for Windows 10 (including dependency injection), please check the [official GitHub repo](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism). There are some samples available as well in [this repo](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Windows).